# Biblatex --- how to add colon after volume?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

How does one place a colon after the volume and before the page range for articles?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author =   {First I. Last, and Second Y. Author},
  title =    {This is the article title},
  journal =  {T Journal T},
  journallongtitle =     {The Journal Title},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   50,
  pages =    {30--40}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What style do you use? Would you mind preparing a short MWE?

Comment: It does not become clear what style you use. Is it the standard style (`numeric`)?

Comment: I haven't been able to influence this regardless of the style I've tried --- I just want to know what command affects this and how to apply said command.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The following works with either the default `numeric` or with the `authoryear` style but really only makes sense with the `authoryear` style since in the `numeric` style, the year comes after the volume.  The punctuation before the pages is controlled by the macro `\bibpagespunct`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Reference:1994,
  author =   {First I. Last, and Second Y. Author},
  title =    {This is the article title},
  journal =  {T Journal T},
  journallongtitle =     {The Journal Title},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   50,
  number = 6,
  pages =    {30--40}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\begin{document}
\autocite{Reference:1994}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Apparently my MWE is too minimal --- I applied your change, but it didn't work in my full file. I'll have to see about making a longer question which more fully addresses my needs. Thanks!

Comment: @WillAdams But then you must be using a particular `biblatex` style that changes some of this.  Without knowing what that is, it will be hard to solve.

Comment: Shouldn't the last change made over-ride anything which went before?

Comment: @WillAdams Only if the relevant style uses the same bibmacros to print out the volume and pages. If it doesn't then changing what I suggested won't have any effect.

Comment: This solution will also replace the comma with a colon for entries that aren't journal articles. While the colon is common for journal articles, it is not common for articles in edited volumes.

Answer (score 3):

This solution will add the colon only for journal articles (which is the only place you would want this, I believe). I've also removed the "In:" and "pp.", which I think are unusual solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    AUTHOR = "John Doe",
    TITLE = "My article",
    JOURNALTITLE = "A Cool Journal",
    VOLUME = "16",
    PAGES = "18--56",
    YEAR = "2005"}
@incollection{mycontrib,
    AUTHOR = "Peter Smith",
    TITLE = "My contribution",
    BOOKTITLE = "A collection of articles",
    EDITOR = "John Carpenter",
    YEAR = "2010",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PAGES = "685--764"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace}{\addcomma\addspace}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle,mycontrib}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]