# Add colon after volume + number

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex for this. I would like to change the comma to a colon after vol (num) in articles. Currently, the format is:

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. (1989). Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications **7 (4)**,
>   458–465.

And I would like to have (without affecting others, such as inbook):

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. (1989). Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications **7 (4):**
>   458–465.

What I have done so far is:

```
\usepackage[
  refsection=chapter,
  firstinits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  mincitenames=1,
  maxcitenames=2,
  minbibnames=3,
  maxbibnames=5,
  style=authoryear,
  dashed=false,
  backend=bibtex
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1} 
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\textbf{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
    \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
      \printfield{volume}
      \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}
      \printfield{number}
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
      \printfield{eid}
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141798/35864), if you only want this for articles, go with `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma\space}}`.

Comment: Thanks moewe, your suggestion worked. I had already tried to redefine \bibpagespunct, but without including \ifentrytype. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to moewe's comment:

> Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141798/biblatex-how-to-add-colon-after-volume), if you only want this for articles, go with \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma‌​\space}}. –  moewe 19 mins ago

Thanks

Comment: I think you should elaborate a little bit on your answer. Just copying a user's comment is not really a solution (even if he granted to do so ;-))