# Change bibliography formatting with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to change my current citation to desired citation with `biblatex` package. I tried to do this using `apacite` and asked a similar question but got stuck.

Current Citation:

> Abernethy, M. A., Kuang, Y. F., & Qin, B. (2015). The influence of ceo power on compensation contract design. *The Accounting Review*, 90(4), 1265-1306. Retrieved from https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971

Desired Citation:

> Abernethy, M. A., Y. F. Kuang, and B. Qin. 2015. The influence of ceo power on compensation contract design. *The Accounting Review* 90 (4): 1265-1306, https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971

Changes needed

1. After first name, all names to begin with initials and then surname
2. Remove the words 'Retrieved from'
3. Color and Underline the url
4. Remove comma after Journal's name
5. Remove parentheses for year
6. Put colon(:) after issue number
7. Remove final period and put a comma in its place

```
\begin{filecontents}{tempfile.bib}
    @article{abernethy2015influence,
        title={The influence of CEO power on compensation contract design},
        author={Abernethy, Margaret A and Kuang, Yu Flora and Qin, Bo},
        journal={The Accounting Review},
        volume={90},
        number={4},
        pages={1265--1306},
        year={2015},
        publisher={American Accounting Association},
        url = {https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971}, 
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doitext}{}

\addbibresource{tempfile.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}%volume deitalicize

\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doitext}{}

\begin{document}

    \cite{abernethy2015influence}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex-apa` is one of the more complex `biblatex` styles. Its express purpose is to implement the bibliography and citation acquirements of the 7th edition of the APA Publication Manual as closely as possible. That means that it has to jump through quite some hoops to get there. If a choice has to be made between being faithful to APA and being easy to customise, naturally the former is more important. I guess what I'm saying in so many words is: `biblatex-apa` can be really hard to modify. Use it only if you need APA style (or only very few, very small modifications). ...

Comment: ... The bibliography style you describe seems sufficiently dissimilar from `biblatex-apa` that it appears to be more promising to start from a different style altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The following codes will work to get some part of what you want. This mainly copies from file `apa.bbx` with slight changes. You can copy the `apa.bbx` and modify it to get what you want.

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\addspace and\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
     \ifthenelse{\(\iffieldundef{url}\AND\iffieldundef{abstracturl}\AND\iffieldundef{abstractloc}\)\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
       {}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{abstracturl}\AND\iffieldundef{abstractloc}}
         {}
         {\printtext{\bibcpstring{abstract}}\addspace}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield{urldescription}%
          \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}%
          \iffieldundef{url}{}{\printfield{url}\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}%
          \iffieldundef{abstractloc}{}{\printfield{abstractloc}\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}%
          \iffieldundef{abstracturl}{}{\printfield{abstracturl}\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}}
```

This mainly copy from file `apa.bbx` with slight changes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I think that the style you want is sufficiently different from `biblatex-apa` that it is a good idea to base your style on a different, more customisable style than `biblatex-apa`. `biblatex-apa` was specifically designed to implement the complex APA style requirements and is not intended to be arbitrarily customisable.

Usually one of the standard styles is a better base for a customised style. Here I chose a style from my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), because it has some features that make our life a bit easier here.

Some relevant links

- [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864)
- [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864)
- [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864)
- [Biblatex --- how to add colon after volume?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141798/35864)

Of course it is not possible to design a complete style from just one example of an `@article` bibliography entry, but this should get you started.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\newunitpunct}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addnbspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:doi} and not test {\iffieldxref{doi}}}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:eprint} and not test {\iffieldxref{eprint}}}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:url} and not test {\iffieldxref{url}}}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abernethy2015influence,
  title   = {The Influence of {CEO} Power on Compensation Contract Design},
  author  = {Abernethy, Margaret A. and Kuang, Yu Flora and Qin, Bo},
  journal = {The Accounting Review},
  volume  = {90},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {1265-1306},
  year    = {2015},
  doi     = {10.2308/accr-50971}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{abernethy2015influence}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Abernethy, M. A., Y. F. Kuang, and B. Qin. 2015. The Influence of CEO Power on Compensation Contract Design. The Accounting Review 90 (4): 1265–1306, doi: 10.2308/accr-50971.]